# Node can't enable harmony features

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-6

Trying to run these new features as shown http://h3manth.com/new/blog/2013/es6-on-nodejs/, specifically **Generators** in my local node environment. Any reason when I run `node --harmony --use-strict es6.js` on any Node versions before 0.11.4 I get the errors

```
function *Counter() {
     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
etc...
```

It works on any versions 0.11.4 and after, but when add a `--debug-brk` statement in there I get

```
global.v8debug.Debug.setBreakPoint(compiledWrapper, 0, 0);
                       ^
ReferenceError: break_point is not defined
```

Not sure why it gives me the option to enable harmony, but not utilize it in previous versions, and why can't I debug the later versions?

Comment: Don't use `--use-strict` option. If you're using 3rd party modules, you're forcing strict mode on them for no reason. If you want to use strict mode, you have to specify it at the beginning on your files.

Comment: Theres an issue on their github issue tracker but no response yet
https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7363#issuecomment-43405861

Answer (score 0):

`--harmony-generators` has been added in Node v0.11, that's certainly why your code couldn't be parsed.

Break debugging with `--use-strict` is an issue since now that has just been fixed is [node v0.12 development branch](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/v0.12).

If you feel like building your own version of node from latest sources, you should be able to debug your generator!

Source: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8685